# Rails 3.2.15 "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" although token exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, csrf

I have a form_tag with remote: true. It is for members subscription in newsletter.

I have the "csrf_meta_tags" in my layout. When I submit the form I get the "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" Warning. I want to mention that the csrf_token exist both in the layout and form.

I could not find a good answer on this.

Answer (score 3):

I this when JS is disabled? I usually have this problem, and including `authenticity_token: true` in the form tag solved it for me. [The docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) explain it better.

> :authenticity_token - Authenticity token to use in the form. Use only if you need to pass custom authenticity token string, or to not add authenticity_token field at all (by passing false). Remote forms may omit the embedded authenticity token by setting config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = false. This is helpful when you’re fragment-caching the form. Remote forms get the authenticity from the meta tag, so embedding is unnecessary unless you support browsers without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by adding back my turbolinks stylesheets and javascripts.

Try adding to application.html.erb head tag:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```